# Yeoman generator gulp-angular deployment on Azure websites

Tags: azure, yeoman, azure-web-app-service, yeoman-generator-angular

I have developed my frontend using gulp-angular (yeoman generator). it's working fine on local environment. I want to deploy this on azure websites. I have uploaded code on azure websites but I am unable to start the server.

```
gulp serve   //to start server on Local
gulp build   //to create a build for Production
```

How can I run gulp build command on azure websites.

Is there any deployment script to run on azure websites?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build your project on the server then you could look into creating your own [custom deployment script](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/custom-web-site-deployment-scripts-with-kudu/).

The challenge here is that you'll have to npm install the dev tools as well, and that might cause issues with MAX_PATH.  Give it a shot and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

With Yeoman angular your code gets generated to the dist folder, which is by default excluded from the git enlistment.

You can work around this by doing the following:

1. Remove the `/dist` line from your .gitignore file
2. Add a .deployment file to your code the root folder of your project and paste the following inside it to tell Azure Web Apps to treat the dist folder as the root of your web app:

   [config]
   project = dist

You can find more detailed instructions here: 
http://www.zainrizvi.me/2015/10/13/deploy-statically-generated-sites-to-azure-web-apps/

Comment: Thanks Zain for this quick and easy deployment tip. but I want to create build on server automatically whenever I push my code. like I push my changes into git repository and gulp generate build on server and deploy this for production. can u please guide me how can i achieve this?